# Desktop Client for Google+ and Hangout

Tags: software-recommendation, google, google-plus

Is there any app that I can use to do **Google Hangout** from within my Ubuntu Desktop like **Skype**?

Also, How can I integrate **Google+** account with Ubuntu?

Comment: https://github.com/xmikos/qhangups. For some strange reason I cannot post an answer.

Comment: In order to help/ease the search process you could add some other tags like `google-hangouts` or `gtalk`

Comment: Pidgin has a hangouts plugin that is usable it isn't amazing but it gets the job done. i.e. the libpurple-hangouts addon.

Comment: gmail has a chat interface to hangouts.  Works reasonably well.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There is currently no desktop native app for Google Hangouts. As far as I am aware all usage for Google Hangouts is done through a web browser.

Comment: The hybrid desktop-plugin + browser combo provides the desktop style experience, as noted in several of the other answers.  Specifically, William Hilton's and Dean Rather's.

Comment: For all those who look at my answer, the one below by lacexd is now the most accurate. You can get it here http://www.google.com/+/learnmore/hangouts/

Comment: Technically, yes, though if you have Chrome installed and allow it to run in the background, then you can have Hangouts running without any browser windows open.

Comment: only one issue, each hangouts window - it is chrome window, so i have alot problem with window focus on hangouts. it is always catch focus when i pres Alt+ tab and choose chrome

Answer (score 37):

## How to install **Google Hangout**:

1. Go to [the Google+ Hangouts page](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/hangoutplugin) and click in the *Download Plugin* button.

   [image: click_button_0]
2. Then you will see a list containing options with binary files, this page will read your system information and select automatically the best option for you. Click in the *Download Link* button and save the file in your computer.

   [image: click_button_1]
3. When the download is complete, open the file (double click over it).

   [image: open_file]
4. It will be open with the *software-center*, click in the *Install* button. If it request for your password, enter it.

   [image: click_button_2]
5. The installation will start there and, in the *Progress* label you will see a progress bar.

   [image: installation_start]
6. After a seconds the install will end and you will see the status of this applications as *Installed*.

   [image: soft_status]

Now, in [the previously visited download page](https://tools.google.com/tools/dlpage/res/talkvideo/en/success.html), you will see that it's installed on your system and you can start to use Google+ Hangouts!

[image: web_confirmation]

Comment: Its again browser based. I was looking for a desktop app. Anyway, thanks for your help.
Is it possible to use `Hangout` like `Skype`, I mean like a desktop app?

Comment: Oh, well.. I did never see that it could be used like an app. Let see if someone knows if its possible. And, when you say *integrate Google+ account with Ubuntu* do you mean like [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/07/google-unity-launcher) or how?

Comment: Possibly adding the account the same way you'd add a facebook or twitter account to Online Accounts to use G+. @TheKojuEffect Why don't you make it a Web App?.

Comment: @UriHerrera I'm agree with you. Also, the OP could install the [Gnome Gmail](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-gmail/) and/or [Gmail Notify](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gmail-notify/).

Comment: Does this need Chrome? It won't open for me

Comment: In the time, I tested this on Firefox as you can see by the screenshoot. No idea the current status.

Answer (score 24):

The instructions listed are good, but if what you are looking for is the *desktop* version of Hangouts, then I recommend installing the Google Chrome extension. Go to http://www.google.com/hangouts/ and click the "Available for your computer" link at the bottom. Despite being a Chrome extension, it makes Hangouts live in their own windows outside of the browser.

Comment: And due to it being a Chrome extension, it requires Chrome constantly be running (that's bloat right there), will crash with Chrome, etc.

Comment: This is a good option, and I use it now. But the main problem I have is that I'm used to running a chat client like Pidgin, so ideally Hangouts would integrate with that. +1 nonetheless.

Comment: At the moment, the link is called **For your computer**.

Comment: Running Chrome as a background app does not make it bloatware if you are already using Chrome as your default browser. It's more like a service that allows you to launch lightweight apps instead of each plugin running as a standalone app.

Answer (score 20):

they made a desktop client for hangouts. its still a chrome extension but if you allow running chrome in the background hangouts will run like a standalone hangouts app.[image]

It can be tricky because there are two hangouts apps in the chromewebstore.

Comment: This is very close to what everyone is wanting. You can close Chrome (the browser window) and this will still run just fine. In addition, you can pin (lock) it to your launcher, and launch it independently of Chrome. Pretty cool.

Comment: Finally, something I can get behind. How they just need to get rid of that white background.

Comment: this white background is very annoying...

Answer (score 6):

> Is there any app that I can use to do Google Hangout from within my
>   Ubuntu Desktop like Skype?

Try using Jitsi...

https://jitsi.org/Main/Download

You can use your google account and also make video calls to your friends from the list. Also, if the other person is using jitsi client, the calls can be encrypted. I tried this today with my friend who had a google account and was using jitsi. The performance was decent. Please try with some one who has a google account but not the jitsi client and let me know. I have not tried the video conference feature yet.

For the second question i have no answer as of now :(

Comment: Does it work with group chat?

Comment: Not a bad option, but it's java based... very slow to load.

Answer (score 4):

You may use empathy as your Hangouts client for Google chat :-)
I'm just using like that. simple n lovely. just Hangout smiley faces are missing which i think you can fix that with plugin (if someone made that)

Comment: Empathy, as far as I know, does not support group hangouts. It's more than just the hangouts emoji missing.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately the group chat doesn't work. It's fine for individual conversations but this is a sorely missing feature.

Answer (score 4):

Google offers their own Ubuntu client, it's pretty good.

http://www.google.com/hangouts/

It is kind of a Chrome hybrid, in that it does require Chrome to be running, but does create its own Desktop windows.

Comment: It's a Chrome app so Chrome continues running in the background, along with some of the awful plug-ins that are sadly necessary. It does work with group chat, however. Annoyingly, though, it cannot be maximised.

Comment: Chrome is black-hole for memory usage, so I always avoid using Chrome or it's apps. I only use chrome just because of Postman app.

Comment: now its a tab without installation. i like it very much

Answer (score 4):

Take a look here [Hangouts extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hangouts/nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd)
It adds a button to chrome and tray icon.
Good luck

Answer (score 4):

**YakYak**

Cross platform desktop client for hangouts built in electron

[Download](https://github.com/yakyak/yakyak/releases)

[image]

Comment: i've had problems with it lately. also the lack of PPA is troubling

Answer (score 2):

You can try **[Franz](https://meetfranz.com/)**, which is an app based on [Electron](https://electronjs.org/). It lets you add a Google Hangouts account (and many other popular instant messaging platforms).

[image]